# Is it possible to convert the result of the LINQ "Take" extension method to the original type?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sortedlist

If I apply the LINQ `Take` extension method to a `SortedList<int, int>`, how do I convert the result to a new `SortedList<int, int>`?

From the runtime error I'm getting, the result of the Take method is an `EnumerablePartition` which cannot be cast to `SortedList<int, int>`

Main method in console App compiles OK, but throws an error at runtime when casting the result of list.Take(2) to SortedList

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List");

            var list = new SortedList<int, int>();

            list.Add(2, 10);
            list.Add(8, 9);
            list.Add(3, 15);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in list){
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Short List");

            var shortlist = (SortedList<int, int>)list.Take(2);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in shortlist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            };

            Console.Read();

        }
```

I would have expected the result of the `Take` method to be a new `SortedList<int, int>` or at least that it would be possible to cast to a `SortedList<int, int>` given that this is the original type.

Here's the runtime error I'm getting:

`` Unable to cast object of type 'EnumerablePartition`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]' ``

EDIT:

I'm relatively new to LINQ and Generics, but thanks to excellent answers provided, I've created a new extension method for readability:

```
    static class Extensions {

        public static SortedList<TKey, TValue> ToSortedList<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> collection)
        {
            var dictionary = collection.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
            return new SortedList<TKey, TValue>(dictionary);
        }
    }
```

Now, to create my shortlist:

```
var shortlist = list.Take(2).ToSortedList();
```

I was thinking that something like the above might already be available!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> given that this is the original type

Yes, but `Take()` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, and `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

So the type you get back from `Take()` doesn't have to have any relation to the source you call it on - it merely returns an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the same type as `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` you call it on.

Instead instantiate a new list using the partition and its [appropriate constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_SortedList__ctor_System_Collections_IDictionary_):

```
var shortlist = new SortedList<int, int>(list.Take(2).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value));
```

Answer (score 8):

> I would have expected the result of the Take method to be a new SortedList or at least that it would be possible to cast to a SortedList given that this is the original type.

Well, it does not quite work that way. If you `Take(2)` from a bag of sweets, you have two sweets. You don't magically have a new bag with two sweets in it just because the original sweets came in a bag.

Technically speaking, the `Take` method takes an `IEnumerable<>` of any type and returns an `IEnumerable<>` of the same type. The information of the original container type is lost in the process.

Now obviously, as in our sweets example, if you *want* to have tiny bags of two sweets each from your big bag, there is no one stopping you from repackaging them. Same here. If you need a sorted list, create a new sorted list from the result. But that's manual.

Comment: This is a great analogy for the `IEnumerable<>` extension methods that I will have to co-opt. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SortedList` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_SortedList__ctor_System_Collections_IDictionary_)

```
var sortedList = new SortedList<int, int>(list.Take(2).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Take` doesn't return a `SortedList` so you need to create a new one one way or another:

```
var shortList = new SortedList<int, int>();
foreach (var x in list.Take(2))
   shortList.Add(x.Key, x.Value);
```